# Testing the class of an object: conditional against class, class[1] versus is?

Tags: r

In R, when defining a conditional statement testing the class of the object, I could write either:

```
if (class(myObj)[1] == "data.frame")
```

or

```
if (is(myObj, "data.frame"))
```

Are there scenarios where these may behave differently? Is there a reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: You could use `is.data.frame` directly. i.e. `is.data.frame(mtcars)` or `inherits(mtcars, "data.frame")`

Comment: inherits is the correct function to test for an arbitrary S3 class. Martin Mächler said so in his useR keynote. Your first option makes an assumption about the order of classes.

Comment: `inherits` is preferred over `is`?

Comment: @Josh Read the "See Also" in `help("is")`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `is.data.frame` directly

```
is.data.frame(mtcars)
```

Or with `inherits`

```
inherits(mtcars, "data.frame")
```

Comment: `data.frame` is an example, I'd like to know for any arbitrary class. But this doens't address the question, why/when would you use `inherits` over `is`?